# Create a database from a property advert website

Tags: database, web

I need to keep track of real estate selling prices, and here in Greece there is a property advert website that features thousands of ads in a systematic way like this:

http://1drv.ms/1gwJhRe

Every advertisement has a title, then the region and a small description and finally on the right the area and selling price.

I understand that they have a database where everything is stored, but this isn't accessible directly.

Trying to make a spreadsheet by extracting data one by one will take years.

How could I create a software that would end up creating a text file with tabulated data (region, area, selling price, ...)  from each and every one of the ads?

I am willing to study hard in order to learn what it takes for this.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you will need to perform something called Web Scraping. Check out [Scrapy.org](http://Scrapy.org)

A crawler is program that would read the HTML doc and can interpret it in a format you need.